# DIY Spectrometer/Colourimeter 430nm and Log Amps, Are all log amps equal in this case?

Tags: operational-amplifier

received some good help in the past on another project (vacuum pump). I'm now moving on to my current project, to build a colourimeter or 430nm spectrometer for measuring the colour of beer.

This project will be encased in a wooden box with brass fixtures and fitting and use an analog output device - I'm thinking of a needle Voltmeter with a graduated colour scale, but that's quite a way down the track.

Currently, I am following this paper, http://www.academia.edu/6985992/Simple_Cheap_and_Portable_Colorimeter_for_Introductory_Analytical_Chemistry_Laboratories as the starting point using a 430nm diode and some white Das modeling clay to make a cuvette holder and housing for the LED and LDR. However it relies on resistance measurement with a multimeter, which is not part of my longterm plans.

So, I'm going to need a log amp to produce a voltage output. Which, I believe, is where all the fun begins. I guess I could build a log amp circuit, but temperature compensation, apparently, is critical to accuracy especially when dealing with transmissive sampling.

I've also looked at two log amps, the Texas Instruments LOG112 & the Analog Devices ADL5306. The first is insanely expensive, and the second not available via ebay.de which brings me to the question: for this particular application, what other options do I have, or should I just bite the bullet and get the LOG112 and move on?

Comment: Why not use a dedicated [colour sensor](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/sensors-transducers/color-sensors/1966897?k=Color%20sensor)?? eBay is not really a great source for components that you need to work, by the way. Could even drive you to drink.

Comment: What sort of dynamic range are you expecting? It might just be simpler to have a series of selectable gains, and pick the one that gives you a decent reading.

Comment: For the diode itself,I would recommend mounting it on a TEC (Peltier) and control the temperature.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if you can avoid a microprocessor in your project, which makes calibration way easier. You can build in a simple signal generator and switch it in automatically before each measurement. That solved the problem of calibrating the amp, but not the sensor. Though you could probably program a compensation curve in the processor too.

There are several solutions for log amps. Look at [this info from Maxim](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3611). It shows the basic theory on how a DC log amp works. Consider that the commercial amps are expensive because they have to compensate internally - you can do that with software.

A trick is to put a series of amplifiers in series, and sum their output. One by one the amplifier will start to saturate, and provide a piece-wise approximation. [This circuit](http://www.tradeofic.com/Circuit/1408-DC_TO_VIDEO_LOG_AMPLIFIER.html) does that, but the amplifiers are expensive because they're supposed to work till video. For DC work, any amp should work.

[Another interesting article](http://www.poulpetersen.dk/xfiles/cir/gblogamp.html) show that even simple circuits can provide quite good results.

I wonder if modulating the light source could provide for a calibration of the entire system...